# 'Advanced' Batch Code With BITSADMIN?

Tags: batch-file

So, I was making a simple 'Updater' program with batch. I was able to find and use this code:

```
bitsadmin /transfer Download /download /priority normal http://downloadsite.com/file.zip c:\file.zip
```

I was wondering if it was at all possible for it to compare files or something similar?
For example, in the installation directory there is a file named 'Test.exe' and the same named file is on a download site. Depending on which file is larger, it will either download the new file or keep the old. Possible?

Comment: No, bitsadmin [doesn't have](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362813(v=vs.85).aspx) any file listing or updating commands, you'll have to download to a temporary folder and then compare the files. There's a much better tool for this task: `wget`.

Comment: @wOxxOm Alright that's fine. Didn't think the bitsadmin command could do it.

Comment: You could download them both and use `FC` to compare them? For my programs I keep a text file and have version numbers for the downloads.